# How to install steam through Ubuntu Software Center without logging into Ubuntu One

Tags: software-center, steam

I'm on 13.04 and I can't see any option to install steam directly through Ubuntu Software Center without logging in with Ubuntu One account. How can I access Ubuntu Software Center and install steam without logging in to Ubuntu One?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download Steam from here: http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb.

After download, if you double click on the downloaded file, this it will be open with Ubuntu Software Center and you can install it without logging into Ubuntu One.